# Multiple data type input in C# function

Tags: c#, .net, arduino, .net-micro-framework, netduino

I am switching from an Arduino (c language) to a Netduino (c# language).

In my arduino program I have the following function (built-in):

[Constrain](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/constrain)

I would like to convert this to C#. I have the following code:

```
int ConstrainValue(int value, int min, int max)
    {
        int Value = value;
        int Min = min;
        int Max = max;

        if (Value >= Max)
        {
            Value = Max;
            return Value;
        }
        else if (Value <= Max)
        {
            Value = Min;
            return Value;
        }
        return Value;
    }
```

However, I would also like to be able to use this for the `double` datatype. Is it possible to modify the function so multiple datatypes can be used?

Comment: Does Netduino support Generics?

Comment: You will have to copy/paste a few overloads of this for different data types. The most practical solution.

Comment: I think the second comparison should compare to `Min`, not `Max` again. Also in .NET value types are passed by value, not by reference, so you don't need to create the capitalized copies.

Comment: You could modify the method and use `double`s instead of `int`s. That way you won'z lose precicion...

Comment: @sll No, generics are not available in micro framework http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327036/net-micro-framework-and-unsupported-features-what-is-the-impact

Answer (score 5):

It is, using `IComparable`.

```
static T ConstrainValue<T>(T value, T min, T max) where T : IComparable
{
    if (value.CompareTo(max) > 0)
        return max;
    else if (value.CompareTo(min) < 0)
        return min;
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, you need to make it a generic function, something like that:

`T ConstrainValue<T>(T value, T min, T max) where T : IComparable`

I think you'll need to add some more interfaces though

Comment: But this would cause boxing for all numeric types. Not ideal.

Comment: @Jon Are you sure it won't just constraint the types you use at the build time? (I'm actually really asking, never thought that kind of implementation causes boxing...)

Comment: `CompareTo` takes an object - so you get boxing there.

Comment: indeed, never thought about that, well I learned something today thx :)

Answer (score 1):

By specifying `struct`, you will not get boxing when calling the method, but by using `IComparable` you will still get it when calling `CompareTo` because that interface method takes an `object`.

So use `IComparable<T>` and I'm pretty sure there's no boxing now:

```
    private static T ConstrainValue<T>(T value, T min, T max)
      where T : struct, IComparable<T>
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(max) > 0)
        {
            return max;
        }

        if (value.CompareTo(min) < 0)
        {
            return min;
        }

        return value;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies! However, I get the following error on IComparable<T>: The non-generic type 'System.IComparable' cannot be used with type arguments. And on .CompareTo: 'T' does not contain a definition for 'CompareTo' and no extension method 'CompareTo' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I dunno - there's nothing wrong with that code, and only using needed is `using System;`. But then you are using the .net micro framework, which may not have a generic `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: Indeed, generics are not available in micro framework http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327036/net-micro-framework-and-unsupported-features-what-is-the-impact My answer will not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

By using generics you can use multiple datatypes

T ConstrainValue(T value, T min, T max) where T : IComparable

Answer (score 0):

.net micro (netduino) does **NOT support generics** as of v4.2.

You would have to use another scheme such as a function that takes objects as arguments and then does the work.  You'll then have to use 'as' or casting on the return in the calling function:

```
    object ConstrainValueInt(object value, object min, object max)
        {
   /* this could still get you in trouble with bool type */
          if (value.GetType().isValueType && min.GetType().isValueType && max.GetType().isValueType )
          return ( (value >= max)? max : ((value <= min)? min : value));
        }
```